# Querying multiple columns at the same time in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to convert a script I found online to search data from numerous columns rather than one. The problem with my code is that it will only grab data from one column. It will search and focus on all columns as I type but if I use two words they HAVE to be in the same column to display.

This is the original query in the script.

```
WHERE webslesson_post_title LIKE "%'.str_replace(' ', '%', $_POST['query']).'%"
```

This was my adjustment.

```
WHERE (Name LIKE '%".str_replace(' ', '%', $_POST['query'])."%' OR Address LIKE '%".str_replace(' ', '%', $_POST['query'])."%' OR City LIKE '%".str_replace(' ', '%', $_POST['query'])."%' OR State LIKE '%".str_replace(' ', '%', $_POST['query'])."%' OR ZIP LIKE '%".str_replace(' ', '%', $_POST['query'])."%')
```

The script started with searching one column of data. I needed it to search a name, address, city, state, zip columns. I want to be able to search a street and a zip and see all results. Or a name and city. Just any combination.

Comment: this seems to be totally vulnerable to sql injection attacks, where did you get that code from? it's a really really really bad code

Comment: `as I type` implies that there is a GUI portion of this, am I right? Like you're making an AJAX call to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can form a concatenated string from multiple columns and compare it to your search pattern.

```
WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', Name, Address, City, State, Zip) LIKE ?
```

This shows using a parameter placeholder. This is recommended, because it avoids all that complicated string-concatenation, and it is more secure.

Run it in PHP like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT ...full query... ";
$search = "%" . str_replace(' ', '%', $_POST['query']) . "%";
if (($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)) !== false) {
  if ($stmt->execute( [ $search ] ) !== false) {
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
  } else {
    error_log(print_r($stmt->errorInfo(), true));
  }
} else {
  error_log(print_r($pdo->errorInfo(), true));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It was exactly what I needed. I just earned the privilege to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to searching through individual columns manually is to create a full text index on the desired columns. The query then becomes much simpler.

For example, to search through columns a and b create a table will full text index over desired columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `a` text,
  `b` text,
  FULLTEXT KEY `a` (`a`,`b`)
)
```

And the query would look like:

```
select * from test where match(a,b) against ('ddd');
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match